# To fetch last inserted value from db using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database in which every minute a new value is inserted and I want to fetch the latest inserted value each minute continuously

```
cursor = connection.cursor () 
cursor.execute ("select time from gbp_inr_min order by id desc limit 1")
while True:
       row = cursor.fetchone
       print (row)

       time.sleep(60)
connection.close ()
sys.exit()
```

Whenever I run this code it gives correct output for the very beginning after that it just shows `NONE`

Comment: `row` is equal to `Cursor.fetchone` method, which I suppose should be called to obtain a row like `row = cursor.fetchone()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your query

```
cursor.execute ("select time from gbp_inr_min order by id desc limit 1")
```

every time in a loop, since after this line no more queries are performed, and so, the cursor can fetch only the row which was returned *at the time of its execution* (since your query has `LIMIT 1`, so it's an expectable result to return a single row and nothing more).

Comment: I did what you said `while True:
                        cursor.execute ("select time from gbp_inr_min order by id desc limit 1")    
 row = cursor.fetchone
        
                

        print (row)`

But it gives an error`<bound method Cursor.fetchone of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7ff438fede10>>
`

Comment: @VibhorKarnawat and it still doesn't work?
Upd: see Azat Ibrakov's comment, you need parentheses

Comment: Did you read Azat Ibrakovs comment to the question? `cursor.fetchone` is just a reference to the `fetchone` method. You have to call it by adding parentheses: `cursor.fetchone()`.